# Can I add servlet without restart my project

Tags: java, spring, servlets

Now I do not want to add a Servlet with register in my web.xml but use a annotation , and use it in  my project without restart.

Comment: Please clarify your question

Comment: I think this is a good question and pretty clear. Op wants to add a new servlet to a running web application.

Comment: What is not clear is what "restart" means. No restart of the server, or no restart (/redeploy) of the webapp?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Annotation `@WebServlet` with your servlet class.Something as Below

```
    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/HelloWorldServlet", loadOnStartup = 1)     
     public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
         //your stuff
    }
     }
```

for more details please look in to [This](http://www.concretepage.com/java-ee/jsp-servlet/how-to-create-servlet-without-web-xml-webservlet-annotation-in-servlet-3)

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat allows reloading of classes: https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-reload
You can use this to reload the application when changes are detected. Reloading means the application keeps on running, but the servlet context and all servlets are reloaded, including any new ones. I think this would be the simplest solution, but maybe not exactly what you want, since all the other servlets are also reloaded.

As an alternative you could do something (a bit ugly) with  a '[front controller](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/frontcontroller-135648.html)' servlet which forwards requests to POJO controllers:

```
@WebServlet(value="/myapp")
public class FrontControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    String pageClass = request.getParameter("pageClass");
    String pageClassFullyQualified = "com.myapp." + pageClass;
    Class<?> pageClass = Class.forName(pageClassFullyQualified);
    Constructor<?> constructor = pageClass.getConstructor();
    Object object = constructor.newInstance();
    Page page = (Page) object;
    page.handle(request, response);
}
```

The Page interface:

```
public interface Page { 
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response);
}
```

An example Page class:

```
package com.myapp;

public class MyPage implements Page {
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // handle the request
    }
}
```

You call the application with the page class name (without the package):

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp?page=MyPage
```

And the front controller should instantiate the class and pass the request/response to it. If Tomcat detects a new Page and loads it automatically this should allow hot deploy of a single page.

Of course this is just a proof of concept. Requiring class names as request parameters is extremely bad practice because you are exposing internals to the client.